# Shooting Method for Numerical Solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

I am trying to solve the following nonlinear differential equation using the shooting method. The equation is a boundary value problem with boundary condition x[0]=Pi and x[Infinity]=0. In order to avoid singularity, I am using x[0.0001]=Pi and x[xmax]=0. My solution is okay up to some finite value like it is zero but after it gives oscillation. I don't need these oscillation and need zero just like before the oscillation started. 
My code is

```
sols13 = NDSolve[{x''[
       r] + (1/r) x'[r] - (0.5/r^2) Sin[2 x[r]] + (2/r) Sin[x[r]]^2 - 
      0.2 Sin[x[r]] - Sin[2 x[r]] == 0, x[0.00001] == Pi, 
    x[100] == 0}, x[r], {r, 0.00001, 100}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0.00001] == Pi, 
       x'[0.00001] == -1.117876}}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[r] /. sols13], {r, 0.00001, 100}, 
 AxesLabel -> {r, \[Theta][r]}, LabelStyle -> "Input", 
 PlotRange -> All]
ParametricPlot[{x[r] /. First@sols13, D[x[r] /. First@sols13, r]} // 
  Evaluate, {r, 0.00001, 100}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {\[Theta][r], \[Theta]'[r]}, LabelStyle -> "Input"]
```

I used a parametric plot to find the value of x'[0.0001] in order to get the desired plot.

Comment: You appear to be trying to integrate along a separatrix, which always is numerically unstable.  The best you can do with the shooting method is to integrate along the separatrix for a while, and then stop (say at `r == 7`).  If for some reason you need to integrate further, improve your guess for `x'[0.00001]`.  By the way, the large `r` solution you obtained is valid, except that it  does not match the boundary condition at `r == 100`, as pointed out by the error messages you received.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method of the false transient  works well here

```
rmin = 10^-6; L = 10^2; nn = 2137; tmax = 10; X = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[x[r, t], r, 
      r] + (1/r) D[x[r, t], r] - (1/2/r^2) Sin[
       2 x[r, t]] + (2/r) Sin[x[r, t]]^2 - 1/2 Sin[x[r, t]] - 
     Sin[2 x[r, t]] == D[x[r, t], t], x[rmin, t] == Pi, x[L, t] == 0, 
   x[r, 0] == Pi (L - r)/(L - rmin)}, x, {r, rmin, 100}, {t, 0, tmax},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> nn, "MaxPoints" -> nn, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, 
  MaxSteps -> 10^6]

{Plot3D[X[r, t], {r, rmin, 100}, {t, 0, tmax}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[X[r, tmax], {r, rmin, 100}, AxesLabel -> {r, \[Theta][r]}, 
  LabelStyle -> "Input", PlotRange -> All],
 ParametricPlot[{X[r, tmax], Derivative[1, 0][X][r, tmax]}, {r, rmin, 
   100}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {\[Theta][r], \[Theta]'[r]}, 
  LabelStyle -> "Input", AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you. I will apply this method.

Comment: You're welcome. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=method+of+the+false+transient+